# Displaying all tests names on Bamboo

Tags: bamboo

Is there a way to display all tests names in Bamboo, instead of only the names of the failed/fixed tests. When I browse to the tests section of the result page of the build, only the total number of tests is displayed, e.g. '30 tests in total'. What I actually want to see is a list of all tests performed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to your build results, choose the test tab and click on the small arrow on the left of the screen.

[image]

A navigator will show up.

[image]

Click on the job for which you want to see the test results and a list with all tests will show up in the right part of the screen.

Comment: You don't get all tests listed together. You'll get a tab with failed tests and another with passed tests.

Comment: Can't believe this is not expanded by default!

Comment: It because it's split by the stage that ran the test.

Comment: @JamesD Tbh, I think it'd still be useful to see all tests from all stages on the tests tab run you haven't selected a specific stage

Answer (score 2):

The way I did this was to go to the Logs section for the test, and click Download.

Then, for TestNG which reports PASSED/FAILED I did:

```
grep -P "(PASSED|FAILED):" xxxxx.log
```

I agree though, it would be helpful to see which tests actually ran from within Bamboo.